# Fatal error for mysqli prepare statement when adding less then comparators

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using this code to select some rows with date less than a certain day. When I put `<=` (less than) in the sql in throws me a fatal error. It works (without error but wrong results) when only adding `=`.

I'm using PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class from https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

```
$params = array($id, $day, $day);
$results = $db->rawQuery("
       SELECT * 
       FROM `forecasts` 
       WHERE `geonameid`=? and (DAY(time_from) <= DAY(?) 
       OR DAY(time_to) <= DAY(?))", $params);
```

> Fatal error: Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM `forecasts` WHERE `geonameid`=? and (DAY(time_from) ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have comparison operators right? It seems to me you want: 
    WHERE `geonameid`=? and (DAY(time_from) >= DAY(?) 
           OR DAY(time_to) <= DAY(?))", $params)

Comment: exactly, isn't it what I wrote?

Comment: I changed one after time_from from <= to >=

Comment: no, that is not the problem. I need to find time periods that include any part of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class problem.
Line 101, function rawQuery

```
$this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

this function strip tags, and result for your query is

```
SELECT * FROM `forecasts` WHERE `geonameid`=? and (DAY(time_from)
```

so you can just replace this line with

```
$this->_query = $query;
```